# PowerShell - Compare Folder Names in Directory to File Names

Tags: performance, powershell, sorting, compare

I am looking for a way to compare all of the folders in a directory to *all* of the files in a directory and report back a list of matches (extension of the file doesn't matter).

I have:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {}
```

-or-

```
(Get-ChildItem $Path -File).BaseName | ForEach-Object {}
```

I couldn't find a simple way that I feel like I'm missing to get only the folder/directory names that don't include the path. I thought there may be something like one of these for that:

```
$file.BaseName $file.FullName -leaf
```

Even then, I'm confused how to check whether the names match?

Also, I put asterisks around all because I thought someone may know a more efficient method, like if the first letter of a folder name doesn't match the first letter of a file name, they wouldn't need to be compared further.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

Using the below answer, I feel like this is closer to what I had intended to ask for, but it still doesn't appear to be working.

```
$path1 = "C:\Users"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -path $path1 -Directory
$Files = (Join-Path (Get-ChildItem -path $path1 -File).DirectoryName (Get-ChildItem -path $path1 -File).BaseName)

Compare-Object $Folders $Files -Property Name -ExcludeDifferent
```

Comment: You may take a look at the cmdlet [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1). It is made to compare objects. ;-)

Comment: To get only the last folder of a path you can use [Split-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Is this the same root directory you're talking about? What is meant with _"list of matches"_ ? Partial matches or exact file basename equals foldername?

Comment: Yes, same root directory. Exact file basename equals foldername. Basically I'm looking for files that have been unzipped to folders. "C:\Users\banana" matches with "C:\Users\banana.rar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a list of filenames with a BaseName equal to one of the foldernames in the source directory, why not simply do:

```
$sourceDirectory = 'C:\Users'
# get an array of foldernames
$folderNames = (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Directory).Name
# output a list of filenames with matching BaseNames
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -File | Where-Object {$folderNames -contains $_.BaseName}).FullName
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the answer. Hope this helps some other people with disk cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

As what Olaf suggested:

```
$path1 = "C:\Test\powershell\folder1"
$path2 = "C:\Test\powershell\folder2"
$Folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $path1
$Folder2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $path2

Compare-Object $Folder1 $Folder2 -Property Name,Length | Where-Object {$_.sideIndicator -eq '=>'}
```

Comment: I took this and tried to make it fit to what I am trying to do. If you are able, could you tell me what I am doing wrong in my edit?   (I want to find files that match the name of a folder in the same directory).

Comment: What I wrote is to compare two folders , maybe its not applicable in your scenario.